# jQuery change text in button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I *need* to change the text in a button but it's not working.  This is what I've come up with thus far:

```
var newElemen = $(<button text='Text changed..'></button>);                  
document.append$(newElemen);
```

I've also prepared a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLf3k/) example.

Comment: I'll fix it for only 2 horses (or a camel), but that's my final offer !

Comment: Ah, what the heck -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zLf3k/1/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't spend too many horses on this.

You need to first look at how jQuery's selector works. It works similar to [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) (if you're not familiar with that I suggest you start with something more basic).

If you need a quick review on [jQuery syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp). In your example you need to use the element selector `$('button')` and then you'll want to apply the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to change the text for the button. So if you put it together. You'll want to select the button and then apply the `text()` function, passing in the string you want to change the text to, to change it's text.

`$('button').text('Insert Text Here');`

Answer (score 2):

Use .text method using button selector

```
$("button").text('Text changed..');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').text('new text');
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zLf3k/3/

1. jQuery selector must be **String**
2. created new DOM element when you use **html element** on jQuery selector
3. use `$(document).append` instead of `document.append$`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').text('some text');
```